# What is the difference between openssl RSA_private_decrypt and RSA_private_encrypt?

Tags: c++, c, openssl, cryptography, rsa

I am not a mathematician (and I ask forgiveness for what I am saying in this post!), but as far as I know RSA encryption and decryption should be the same operation:
M ^ e mod n

where M is what I want to decrypt/encrypt, e is the exponent and n is the module (private in my case).

The confirmation of this is the following: when I want to "sign" a plaintext, I obtain the same signature if I do any of the following operations:

```
RSA_private_encrypt(plain_text.size(), &plain_text[0], &encrypted[0], rsa.get(), RSA_NO_PADDING);

RSA_private_decrypt(plain_text.size(), &plain_text[0], &decrypted[0], rsa.get(), RSA_NO_PADDING);
```

My question is: the RSA_private_encrypt documentation states that "flen must be less than RSA_size(rsa) - 11 for the PKCS #1 v1.5 based padding modes, less than RSA_size(rsa) - 41 for RSA_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING and exactly RSA_size(rsa) for RSA_NO_PADDING". If the operation is the same, why I have this limitation only in the encrypt case?
In fact, if I try to use a plain text shorter than RSA_SIZE (1024 in my case), the decrypt operation succeeeds whilst the encrypt fails.

Please note that I am not using padding (and I know this is unsecure).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`RSA_private_encrypt` says](https://openssl.org/docs/manmaster/crypto/RSA_private_encrypt.html):

> RSA_private_encrypt() signs the flen bytes at from (usually a message digest with an algorithm identifier) using the private key rsa and stores the signature in to. to must point to RSA_size(rsa) bytes of memory.

While [`RSA_private_decrypt` says](https://openssl.org/docs/manmaster/crypto/RSA_public_encrypt.html):

> RSA_private_decrypt() decrypts the flen bytes at from using the private key rsa and stores the plaintext in to. to must point to a memory section large enough to hold the decrypted data (which is smaller than RSA_size(rsa)). padding is the padding mode that was used to encrypt the data.

The passage you're quoting is meant for `RSA_public_encrypt` in the documentation.

---

If no padding is used, then `RSA_private_encrypt` and `RSA_private_decrypt` will result in the same operation. If you specify padding, then `RSA_private_encrypt` will add padding to the given data *before* modular exponentiation and `RSA_private_decrypt` will try to remove padding *after* modular exponentiation, where modular exponentiation means the RSA operation `xc mod n` where `x` is the given data and `c` is always the private exponent for private key operations.

Comment: PHP never should have exposed these... Bad security engineering.... The signer should always receive the document, apply the message formatting and calculate the hash himself/herself.